# non logback java util logging to slf4j bridge?

Tags: java, log4j

I am looking for a good way (perfoemance wise) to bridge between jul and slf4j.

I am not using logback so the "LevelChangePropagator" in logback won't help.

I've found this nice page: http://people.apache.org/~psmith/logging.apache.org/sandbox/jul-log4j-bridge/examples.html, but it's old and looks discontinued.

any ideas?

cirect bridge from jul to log4j can also work (haven't found one though).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j

> The jul-to-slf4j module includes a java.util.logging (jul) handler, namely SLF4JBridgeHandler, which routes all incoming jul records to the SLF4j API

Sounds like what you're looking for?

Comment: not at all. I've mentioned above I need a non logback based solution without the performance hit mentioned by the link you gave.

Comment: It says you can improve performance by installing logback's `LevelChangePropagator` but that doesn't mean that this bridge is anything to do with logback; it's an slf4j bridge. I posted the link because I'd used this before and remembered it; I didn't read too carefully about the pros and cons, I'll leave that to you. If you'd already looked at this then it might have been worth saying so explicitly to save people the time suggesting it.

Comment: I thought my mention of "LevelChangePropagator" was enough to point to the fact I've read the link. Sorry for not being clearer.
Either way - still looking for an answer.
Thanks.